# Unification of Biblical Canons Feasible and Beneficial?

Tags: canon, ecumenism

There are various versions of the Bible, each with its own set of books considered canonical. For instance, the Catholic Bible includes books that are not present in the Evangelical Bible. Additionally, there are historical texts such as the Ethiopian version of the Book of Enoch and the Nag Hammadi scriptures that are recognized in some traditions but not in others.

My question is as follows: Why don't different religious denominations and scholars come together in a council to review and unify the biblical canons? The idea would be to discuss and decide which books should be included or considered apocryphal, based on the latest archaeological, linguistic, and theological evidence.

I believe that a thorough and well-founded review could clarify doubts and unify understandings about the sacred texts. Would such unification be feasible? What might be the potential theological, cultural, and academic consequences of an initiative like this?

Comment: This question was closed on SE-BH. The question demonstrably lacks research into the genuine and foundational reasons for there being disagreement about the content of the canon. The very idea of 'unifying' right and wrong is fundamentally _unrighteous_.

Comment: You might as well ask why denominations are separate -- they could also come together as a council to discuss and unify.

Comment: @eques Vatican II tried to do something like that, but it hardly reunified Christianity ...

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Vatican II attempted many things and did have Protestant observers, but I've never heard the claim it was actually meant to resolve the differences

Answer (score 2):

> Why don't different religious denominations and scholars come together in a council to review and unify the biblical canons?

That wouldn't work because scholars don't identify the canon, nor do councils determine it.

Protestants are the clearest about how Christians actually recognise the canon, as this paragraph from the Westminster Confession of Faith explains:

> [WCF 1.5](https://www.apuritansmind.com/westminster-standards/chapter-1/): We may be moved and induced by the testimony of the Church to an high and reverent esteem of the holy Scripture;
>  and the heavenliness of the matter,
>  the efficacy of the doctrine,
>  the majesty of the style,
>  the consent of all the parts,
>  the scope of the whole (which is to give all glory to God),
>  the full discovery it makes of the only way of man's salvation,
>  the many other incomparable excellencies,
>  and the entire perfection thereof,
> are arguments whereby it doth abundantly evidence itself to be the Word of God;
> yet, notwithstanding,
> our full persuasion and assurance of the infallible truth and divine authority thereof,
>  is from the inward work of the Holy Spirit,
>  bearing witness by and with the Word in our hearts.

This fascinating paragraph lists off many of the characteristics that set scripture apart from other writings, before dismissing them all to say that the ultimate reason we are persuaded that the scriptures are inspired is the inward work of the Holy Spirit and Christ in the lives of believers, witnessing to us.

There is no major group of Protestants who believe the dueterocanon is inspired, there is not even a minor group. Over five centuries hundreds of millions, possible billions, of Protestants been remarkably uniform in their position on the canon, so Protestants like myself can feel quite confident that we have been listening to the witness of the Spirit. And I'd say that we can know that the Spirit has been a witness to the authority of the scriptures because we Protestants fully recognise James as scripture despite our founder Luther's reticence to do so.

Other denominations state that the authority for identifying the canon does not lie in the individual's personal persuasion by the Spirit, such as the Catholic Church:

> [CCC 120](https://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__PR.HTM): It was by the apostolic Tradition that the Church discerned which writings are to be included in the list of the sacred books.

Nonetheless, I think it is still the case that the Spirit is witnessing to the canon for Catholics. If the true canon is the smaller Protestant canon, then some Catholics would be persuaded by the Spirit to leave the Catholic Church, as has happened many times before. Others may feel conflicted but decide to remain within the Catholic Church as they can identify God's authority being within the Catholic Church. And of course many Catholics would say that they do sense the Spirit's witnessing to the whole of the Catholic canon.

Likewise, if the Protestant canon is wrong, then many people will feel the Spirit's witnessing to a larger canon. As Protestantism is not really very accepting of those who believe in a larger canon, they will usually seek out other churches. Many former Protestants have joined the Catholic or Orthodox churches, and it is likely that some of them did so because of the canon each church recognises.

More councils and debates won't be able to unify the canon, because each denomination is quite firm in the canon it identifies. And more councils and debates won't be able to truly identify the canon, because that's not where our confidence in the canon comes from. If there was ever to be any hope of unifying the canon, it would not be through councils and scholars, but instead through encouraging Christians to carefully learn to hear the witnessing of the Spirit.

But even then, I think it is healthy for denominations to be clear and firm about the canon they recognise, rather than being vague and noncommittal. And while the Spirit does witness to us individually, we gain confidence only collectively. I expect that the best practical way for someone to "test" the canon is to listen to expository sermons from different churches. In good sermons "the text does the heavy lifting" (Gary Millar). When you feel encouraged, built up in your faith, moved to love God more, and convicted about lingering sin in your life, and it wasn't the oratory skills of the preacher but the text itself that did this, that is when you are hearing the Spirit witness to the scriptural authority of the text.

Comment: ,are we leaving all the  job to the Spirit? ho has eyes ee, who has ears hear, isn't this a call to acton?

Answer (score 1):

In Germany, the catholic ["Einheitsübersetzung"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einheits%C3%BCbersetzung), while not meant to replace the Luther bible used by the protestants, was a considerable effort to get an ecumenical text.

> The Protestant Church in Germany (Evangelische Kirche in Deutschland,
> abbreviated EKD, which is generally equivalent to the Lutheran church
> in America) was officially requested to work on the translation of the
> Psalms and the New Testament. In 1970, the Bishops' Conference and the
> EKD entered a contract for the joint work on the Einheitsübersetzung,
> which was a major breakthrough of ecumenism in Germany. Since 1980,
> the Einheitsübersetzung has also been approved for use in Protestant
> churches and is especially used with the Luther Translation for
> ecumenical events.

Not all is well though. The [german version of the article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einheits%C3%BCbersetzung) sheds some light on the problems:

> Eine ökumenische Vollbibel zu erstellen, war (und ist) nicht möglich,
> weil die evangelische Seite die griechisch überlieferten Schriften des
> Alten Testaments nicht als Bibel im eigentlichen Sinn anerkennt und
> sie maximal in einem Anhang zum Alten Testament unterbringt. Für die
> katholische Kirche ist aber eine Abstufung der Bedeutung zwischen
> griechischen und hebräischen Schriften des Alten Testaments
> grundsätzlich nicht akzeptabel.

Translation by Google translate but reviewed by me, a native german speaker:

> It was (and is) not possible to produce an ecumenical complete Bible,
> because the Protestant side does not recognize the Greek writings of
> the Old Testament as the Bible in the proper sense and places them at
> most in an appendix to the Old Testament. For the Catholic Church,
> however, a gradation of meaning between Greek and Hebrew writings of
> the Old Testament is fundamentally unacceptable.

And then, when a revision was supposed to happen (quoted again from the english article):

> In the last few years, the Bishops' Conference has attempted a
> revision of the translation. The revision was also supposed to be a
> joint project with the Protestant church. A conflict between the Roman
> Catholic church and the Protestant side arose during the work which
> resulted in the EKD terminating the 1970 contract in 2005. The
> conflict arose from disagreements about the Roman Catholic side's push
> for a heavier emphasis on church traditions than was found in the
> original text [4] and the consensus decision-making process used up to
> that point did not hold, after which common ground between the
> denominations had to be found. After the completion of the revision it
> had to be submitted for a Papal Approbation, which was also rejected
> by the EKD.

According to the german article, there were problems because the catholic side insisted that, when in doubt, the latin version should be used as reference to resolve issues. This is what the english article means when saying "heavier emphasis on church tradition".

> Es kam vor Beginn der Revision zu einem Konflikt zwischen der
> römisch-katholischen und der evangelischen Seite, in dessen Folge die
> EKD den 1970 geschlossenen Vertrag im Jahre 2005 aufkündigte, weil die
> römisch-katholische Kirche auf der Befolgung der römischen Instruktion
> Liturgiam authenticam[12] (28. März 2001) bestehen musste, die die
> revidierte lateinische Bibel (Nova Vulgata) zur Norm bei strittigen
> Entscheidungen machte.

Answer (score 1):

Different Christian denominations are unlikely to come together in a council with scholars to review the canon as the OP hypothesizes because the unity of the Canon is not the pressing issue underlying the division of denominations.

The canon is largely unified as-is; Christian groups broadly fall into one of two categories of Canon: the Hebrew canon exclusively or the Greek canon (which includes the Hebrew books plus some extras).

Almost all of the groups using the Hebrew Canon agree on the same 66 books. They also generally use Sola Scriptura as the doctrinal framework for Scripture.

The groups using the Greek Canon have a large set that everyone agrees on and some groups hold additional texts as canonical.

Most Christian groups do not differ from other groups by a variation of canon; in particular, everyone agrees on the New Testament Canon.

Why are the Protestant groups (using the Hebrew canon) divided from each other? It's not because they differ on canon nor largely on the framework for deriving doctrine (Sola Scriptura). The division must be due to some other doctrinal issue, which would be the topic to resolve if unity were sought.

Why are the Catholic/Orthodox (using the Greek canon) divided from the Protestants (using the Hebrew canon)? We might say that the differences of texts contribute, but that's not the definitive point. The doctrines the Protestants reject are not exclusively derived from the books the Protestants do not recognize. For example, the Catholic doctrine on Eucharist and communion is largely derived from the Synoptic Gospels, 1st Corinthians, John 6, parts of Exodus and Psalms.

The divisions between these groups is based far more on differences of authority than the texts themselves.

Suppose you could convince leadership of various denominations to sit down and discuss the question. What would potentially result? Probably nothing because most of the groups have reasons for the canon they have used for centuries which could not be easily changed without altering the doctrines of those groups significantly (i.e. to such a degree that it would intolerable)

The only way per se to unify the canon is to unify the denominations but that is effectively a trivial observation. One Christian group would tend towards having a single canon.

Answer (score 0):

> Why don't different religious denominations and scholars come together in a council to review and unify the biblical canons? The idea would be to discuss and decide which books should be included or considered apocryphal, based on the latest archaeological, linguistic, and theological evidence.

Protestants grant primacy to the Masoretic Text - both for the text and the canon.

While the Masoretic Text itself is only 1000 years old, the Dead Sea Scrolls have shown it is remarkably faithful to a Hebrew text from around Jesus' time - so it has roots 2000 years old.

The difficulty is the Masoretic Text "canon" - as an explicit list of books, we can trace it to around 170 AD with Melito's list. The difficulty is tracing it before then - we get hints from the preceding centuries with people referring to the "22 books" or "the law, the prophets, and the writings" but no explicit lists.

[One Catholic counterargument](https://www.catholic.com/magazine/online-edition/the-false-prophet-and-the-deuterocanon) to explain the above is that Rabbi Akiba and his followers, shortly before and during the Bar Kokhba revolt, had both the means and the desire to counteract the growing Christian sect that was infecting Judaism. The Christians had the Gospels, and were using the Septuagint which (supposedly) included the Deuterocanonical books like Sirach (or the Book of Wisdom, which the Early Church Fathers used frequently demonstrating its as pointing to Christ). Rabbi Akiba explicitly rejected Sirach (the oldest Dueterocanonical book), everything written after Sirach, and specifically the Gospels as well - thus restricting the canon. Through his student Aquila, he encouraged/released a new Greek translation with this restricted canon to compete against the Septuagint with its greater canon.

Disproving that Catholic theory entirely is impossible (we lack enough specific evidence) - the strongest evidence we have is in the book "The Biblical Canon Lists from Early Christianity: Texts and Analysis" by Protestant authors Meade and Gallagher.

On the flip side of the argument, Catholics point (truthfully) to the Septuagint as the Bible used by early Christians and even Jesus himself, and note that the Septuagint included the Deuterocanon. Catholics note that most of early Christianity therefore accepted the Deuterocanon, and those that didn't often didn't because the Jews were using a smaller canon (blaming Rabbi Akiba for the confusion).

The difficulties with that argument is outlined in "Translation of the Seventy: History, Reception, and Contemporary Uses of the Septuagint" by Protestant author Gallagher. In it, Gallagher basically agrees that Protestants are making a mistake by overemphasizing the Masoretic text over the Septuagint - but that Catholics are making a mistake in claiming their canon is based off the Septuagint. He notes that the "canon" of the Septuagint is based off a Septuagint printed only 100-200 years ago, and that the exact books contained within the Septuagint in the early church fluctuated and there was no set list (so how could you call it a canon?).

Both the Protestant and Catholic arguments have strengths and weaknesses, but they are such that evidence is lacking to completely overcome either argument and convince the other side.

The one interesting wrinkle that has popped up in just the last 20 years is some scholarship on the Dead Sea Scrolls by Emmanuel Tov (and discussed by Gallagher in his book mentioned above on the "Seventy"). The Dead Sea Scrolls prove that the Septuagint was not a bad translation of a Proto-Masoretic text, but rather a good translation of an alternative Hebrew text tradition (and that there were multiple Hebrew text traditions at the time of Christ). That may lead to a reduction in the primacy of the Masoretic over the next several decades, and who knows what will happen as a result of that.

Answer (score -2):

As the comments on your question admit, this is not entirely feasible so long as different denominations hold incorrect doctrines and traditions in higher esteem than actual revelation and the work of gathering God's people.

BUT it has been prophesied that this unification will occur, and the ramifications of this unification are glorious, including ushering in the long-promised Millennium of peace (Revelation 20).

Ephesians 4:13-14

> Till we all come in the unity of the faith, and of the knowledge of the Son of God, unto a perfect man, unto the measure of the stature of the fulness of Christ:
> That we henceforth be no more children, tossed to and fro, and carried about with every wind of doctrine, by the sleight of men, and cunning craftiness, whereby they lie in wait to deceive;

Not only that, but multiple prophecies allude to the unification of additional texts into the canon of Scripture--a seemingly even more difficult task than only unifying on the points of doctrine already conveyed in the Bible in its various editions (see [Ezekiel 37:16-26](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/ot/ezek/37.16-20?lang=eng) and [Isaiah 29](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/ot/isa/29?lang=eng)). Yet the revelation of additional prophetic texts is a manifest necessity, seeing as further revelation is required to clarify the meaning of surviving Biblical texts. The instances when a Biblical dispute could have been settled by "if only Paul were here, he could answer this question", or "if only we had a living prophet or a bona fide apostle we could consult or hear from" are innumerable. But who is willing to receive such additional revelations? Who is willing to change his ways, change course and repent where necessary to reconcile with the revealed word of God, leaving behind constraining and limiting creeds and philosophies of men?

Paul has already previously admonished us regarding these contentions and divisions:
1 Corinthians 1:13

> Is Christ divided? was Paul crucified for you? or were ye baptized in the name of Paul?

Our replies admit the fracture of Christendom is exactly opposite of what God intends to occur at the preaching of His word. Yet  there are more denominations professing Christianity today than there are verses in the Bible.

Therefore what is prerequisite to the prophesied unification? Whatever it is, it has not yet been fully applied, otherwise we would be united. Paul spells out the condition that must precede all coming to the unity of the faith:

Ephesians 4:11-12

> And he gave some, apostles; and some, prophets; and some, evangelists; and some, pastors and teachers;
> For the perfecting of the saints, for the work of the ministry, for the edifying of the body of Christ:

Obviously, the proliferation of teachers, pastors, evangelists and so on in many sects is **not** in fulfillment of this prophecy, nor has it been for thousands of years, because the effect of all false preachers and unrighteous pastors has been the proliferation of denominations and the schism of canons, rather than the unification of them. This is proof that such teachers or professors and their appointments were not given to them by God. A true prophet is needed to overcome these difficulties.

Matthew 12:30

> He that gathereth not with me scattereth abroad.

The approach of most denominations has therefore been to whittle down the emphasized canon, until it would seem so small and so scant as to be impossible to disagree with, but the reverse is true: The more we cherry-pick and isolate verses, the *less* we agree with each other. Conversely, the more we strive to *live by every word that proceeds out of the mouth of God* with all our hearts, the more we are enabled to see eye to eye and bring about Zion. (Isaiah 52:8)

Predictably, the primary result of scholars meeting together to unify canon would only be the creation of **more schism** as new combinatorically complex takes and mental gymnastics on Scripture multiply, since that is what has ensued from all such combinations and creeds thus far.

The Scriptures all point harmoniously to the time of "[the restitution of all things](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/acts/3.21?lang=eng)", when the people of God will be united in [one faith, having one baptism](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/eph/4.5?lang=eng), [one fold and one Shepherd](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/john/10.16?lang=eng).

I believe that many Christians are doing the best they can with what they know, and many look forward to the day spoken of by the writer of Hebrews, wherein:

Hebrews 8:11

> And they shall not teach every man his neighbour, and every man his brother, saying, Know the Lord: for all shall know me, from the least to the greatest.

It is apparent that this condition is impossible to arrive at without the work of teaching prophesied in Ephesians 4:11-12. Therefore our greatest need is for true prophets, not the proliferation of schisms through additional scholarly debates or deconstruction. Even when approached on the initially friendliest of terms, an uninspired effort to force unification has always resulted in further fracture.

### Times of Refreshing

In the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints, we wholeheartedly believe that God has sent us [new prophets](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/general-conference/2022/04/11nelson?lang=eng) [and apostles](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/general-conference/2023/04/57bednar?lang=eng) to bring about this unity of the faith. We believe in the fulfillment of all of these Biblical prophecies, including the prophesied revelation of [additional Scripture](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/bofm?lang=eng) that would settle doubts by the authority of God rather than by the conjectures of scholars. This began with God's calling of [a modern prophet](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/pgp/js-h/1?lang=eng) to usher in the dispensation of the fullness of times (Ephesians 1:10), in which He would gather together in one all things in Christ, to prepare the way for the Second Coming of the Lord.

Unification of canon is possible. It is initiated by God, not by philosophers and scholars of sects contending for their limited doctrines. When the canon is unified, as prophesied, it follows there will ultimately also be only one Christian denomination remaining. Christ is not divided! This generation has a great work to do in reversing the damage of scattering by performing the work of gathering.
Various of my own ancestors joined the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints by delving more deeply into the Bible and believing it more fully than their congregational leaders did. They were willing to set aside limiting creeds and embrace the fullness of God's words, rather than participate further in petty divisiveness and striving for power. They repented of their unbelief and began to participate in God's plan at a higher and more genuinely inclusive level.
Only those who oppose the work of God will be opposed to this unification. Obviously it is not a matter of scholars coming together and giving their best opinions about what should be Scripture. If we do that we will only get more and more schisms as opinions proliferate combinatorically.
The only way to resolve the dilemma is through modern prophets and apostles sent by God Himself to enlighten our minds and prepare us for the Millennium of peace.

What can we do to help? We can repent of our own personal sins, including the ones we have for decades indulged and excused, hiding behind a malinterpretation of some obscure passage, supposing we could get away with it. We can lay aside our dissonance. We can exercise faith in Christ. We can build bridges of understanding with people who see some things differently than we do. We can live up to whatever godly standards we already profess. We can put an end to contentions and divisions by our faith and godly example. The process of unification is taking place as we speak, but it is up to each of us individually to decide whether and how much we are willing to participate.

Comment: About the only part I can agree with is denominations holding incorrect doctrines and that God is the ultimate cause of unity. The rest reads like an advertisement for LDS, which doesn't seem to answer the question for Christians in general.

Comment: @eques If you will remove the dark glasses of bias, you may be able to see this much more clearly for what it is.
The very concession of the fracture of Christianity proves that the whole is not Christianity. That is why this site has to be as accommodating as it is, to avoid falling to pieces altogether, instead of having Methodists SE, Presbyterian SE, Catholic SE, Calvinist Se and so on. People look to Christianity for answers because they know or have faith that it has the answers--and it does. The schisms will continue to be uncomfortable until they are resolved.

Comment: @eques My answer stands and the Scriptures I cite are applicable to every genuine Christian and everyone who seeks to be one. If you feel you can answer it in a way that is better and more recognizeably Christian in general, feel free as always to answer as you see fit.

Comment: Once again you presume too much about me. I do believe in the unity of the Church. I just don't believe in your unity. This site might help with resolving difference only in so far as people may be exposed to them, but fundamentally debating is off-topic in questions/answers (e.g. you cannot answer a Catholicism question from a Lutheran perspective arguing Catholicism is wrong)

Comment: @eques If we believe in unity then we must satisfy the condition foretold by Paul. You can keep trying things, everyone is welcome to do that, and choose his beliefs as he sees fit. But the Lord didn't send His servants to go and hide under a bushel, so that the truth could not be known. I understand this site is not about debate and I have no interest in debating anything, only testifying. Bearing testimony attracts much attempt at debate even when there was nothing said that is debatable. When people ask for factual answers, I am obligated to give what I have that might help, as are we all.

Comment: Matthew 10:34-39 doesn't sound like unification and peace.  There will be Tares amongst the Wheat right up until the harvest and rebellion following the "Millennium".  There will also be a false peace ushered in by Antichrist which the true Church will discern, reject, and be persecuted by.

Comment: @MikeBorden There are many hazards, trials and tribulations leading up to the period when Satan will be bound for a thousand years, but are you saying you do not believe that God will fulfill His promise regarding this period of genuine peace?

Comment: There will be Tares (children of the devil) among the Wheat ( children of the Kingdom) right up to the end...right through the "millennium".

Comment: @MikeBorden You are free to believe that. Whatever you believe I would hope does not contradict any Scripture.

Comment: Matthew 13:39 says the harvest, when the wheat and tares are separated, is the end of the world.

Comment: @MikeBorden If you wish to know, the disambiguation of this term in this context can be found here:
https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/jst/jst-matt/13?lang=eng

Comment: So the end of the world is prior to the millennium, according to LDS?

Comment: @pygosceles, 
One issue is that some individuals are questioning the authenticity of the Bible.do you know this book? Misquoting Jesus: The Story Behind Who Changed the Bible and Why? (https://www.amazon.com/Misquoting-Jesus-Story-Behind-Changed/dp/0060859512)

Comment: @MikeBorden The end of the world or "worldly" precedes the Savior's Second Coming, as John the Revelator attests; the wicked will not be on the Earth. The "world" and the "Earth" are distinct in this important sense; the Savior often refers to the "world" as being the wicked or ungodly inhabitants of the Earth, while the Earth itself will be renewed, although its elements will eventually melt, there will be a new heaven and a new Earth. The Lord Himself having made this distinction clearly, I can hardly find fault with it even when viewed from outside of the latter-day revelations.

Comment: @HumbertoJoséBortolossi It is interesting to see some scholarship on this subject. Candor obliges us to press further on the question whenever someone doubts the authenticity or accuracy of "the Bible": The most natural and honest response I can imagine is, "Which Bible?", as in, "Which translation, which redaction or composition of earlier texts are you referring to? There are many."
Even there, we must recognize that without delving into specific claims about individual passages, questions of whether "the Bible" is authentic are ill-posed, because they are insufficiently precise.

Answer (score -2):

Long version short, no, it's not really possible.

As many of the splintering of Christianity were just as much about power and politics than doctrine. To have them unify would require them sacrificing power to eachother, and honestly, realistically, that's not going to happen, especially when some have built internal culture wars about how sinful other denominations are for "following the wrong path".

Further, many sects thrive specifically on keeping parishioners in the dark on certain aspects of doctrine (for example, the vast majority of Christians don't know *why* Christianity isn't a sect of Judaism.) The majority of dodged different, shall way say, sensitive points, in different ways, and a unification would require addressing those differences in a way that would put nearly every denomination in jeopardy.

For example, can you imagine a unification conversation between a Morman and a Catholic? Prophet vs Pope, each who believes their interpretation is inspired by God, and both interpretations are very, *very* different, and each based on focusing on different aspects of scripture. There's really no way to rectify the Book of Morman + Doctrine & Covenants with ex cathedra of the Catholic Church.

Comment: While I agree that there's no real prospects of the canons being unified, I have no idea what you're trying to insinuate here: "Further, many sects thrive specifically on keeping parishioners in the dark on certain aspects of doctrine (for example, the vast majority of Christians don't know why Christianity isn't a sect of Judaism.)"

Comment: @curiousdannii Many denominations have set interpretations of certain bible verses, and as such, bible verses (or interpretations of bible verses) are strictly not discussed. 

For example, the Catholics have a set progression for liturgy handed down from the Vatican. The understanding is if they attended all sermons, a faithful Catholic will eventually go through the whole Bible. The entire book of Joshua, however, is absent.

Comment: "for example, the vast majority of Christians don't know why Christianity isn't a sect of Judaism" They don't? I would have thought the point that the Jews don't accept Jesus was a given

Comment: @eques That's not the reason at all. It wasn't until the second century that *some* began to *not* see Christianity as a Jewish sect. Before the second century, if you had asked anyone if Christians were Jews, they would have answered "yes" with more certainty than if you asked someone nowadays if Lutherans were Christians.

Comment: @lilHar Your point may be correct historically; my point was correct theologically. There is no way to read the New Testament and conclude the Jews and Christians are going to get along well enough to stick under one umbrella. The division was exacerbated by the Romans who didn't see the Christians as Jews and hence not entitled to the Roman exemptions of worshiping the pagan gods. In any case, that's hardly a topic people are "kept in the dark about"; it doesn't really shape the theological beliefs in any meaningful way.

Comment: Except it does. There may be theological 'reasons', but they were invented *after* the historical reasons. Hiding theology away from historicity and facts de-legitimizes the theology. Jews & Christians both considered Christians a Jewish sect until 70 AD. The big point of separation was the siege of Jerusalem. Christians largely fled, while other Jewish sects stayed. Judaism is a communal religions, so when Christians abandoned the central community of Jerusalem they had also abandoned Judaism itself. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Jerusalem_(70_CE)#In_Jewish_and_Christian_eschatology